# Can't create cloud object storage bucket under lite plan

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am unable to create any cloud object storage bucket -- I need one.
I Keep getting this error when creating one:

[409, Conflict] The account already has an instance created with the Lite plan.

I don't have any existing bucket.

Comment: This is not a programming-related question and you did not provide any commands. Try to open a support ticket or create a non-lite service instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error above is indicating that creating the COS instance is failing because there is already an instance created with the Lite plan.

Background:

In the IBM cloud you must first create an `instance` of the Cloud Object Storage, COS, `service`.  Then you can start creating buckets in the instance.

A `plan` is a very high level feature set and associated price point.  For COS there is a lite and standard plan.  I think the lite plan allows you to kick the tires for free and probably has the expected free tier limitations.